# Why executing powershell cmdlets programmatically (C#) on remote machine (using arguments) doesn't work if I use enter/import-pssession cmdlets?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the PSSession object of the remote machine and say, I am trying to execute "command"

Approach 1 (Invoking enter-pssession before executing actual command):

```
Command cmd = new Command("enter-pssession");
cmd.Parameters.Add("Session",session);
pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
```

Approach 2 (Invoking import-pssession before executing actual command):

```
Command cmd = new Command("import-pssession");
cmd.Parameters.Add("Session",session);
pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
```

Both approaches didnt work and error message is also pretty clear. it says "The term 'Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Approach 3 - works (using Invoke-Command and executing the cmd using scriptblock and session objects)

```
Command cmd = new Command("invoke-command");
cmd.Parameters.Add("session", session);
cmd.Parameters.Add("scriptblock", ScriptBlock.Create(command.ToString()));
if (null != argumentList)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ArgumentList", argumentList);
}
```

I am not blocked as I am using approach #3 and able to carry on with my work.

But I am still not sure why approach 1 or 2 doest work. I believe if I make approach 1 or 2 work, passing named parameters to target machine probably easier.

In other words, as Musaab stated, we can only use enter/import-session cmdlets in interactive mode?

That is exactly my question - why can't I use them programmatically? If I how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

PSSessoions only works in interactive mode, therefore you will have to create a PSSession, then use the Invoke-Command to execute commands on that session.

Comment: Hi - In-other words, thats my question? why cant i use enter/import-pssession programmatically? why can we only use them in interactive mdoe? regards, Dreamer

Comment: It's just the way Powershell is designed. I'm not sure what are the reasons behind it. Sorry if I couldn't add anything helpful, but you can be sure that you're not doing anything wrong, those commands are only for interactive use :-)